# How to repair OrientDB broken links from the java API?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb3.0

I need to repair some broken links in my OrientDB database. Running `REPAIR DATABASE --fix-links` from the console works, but I would like to be able to run it from java (scala actually) code.

I tried to execute the `REPAIR` command as a query but it is not accepted. I also tried to "manually" repair the links by executing commands like

```
UPDATE Comment SET author = NULL WHERE (SELECT expand(author)) is NULL;
```

or

```
UPDATE Comment SET author = NULL WHERE (SELECT expand($parent.$current.author)) is NULL;
```

but they either trigger an error or have no effect.

How can I repair my broken links from the java API?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove the broken links by looking for a property that should be on the linked entity.

```
UPDATE Comment SET author = NULL WHERE author.id IS NULL;
```